# Chrome spellcheck- word change event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, spell-checking

I have a textarea with listener for keyup event. on each keyup event I update the user input. My problem is when user change a word using the chrome dictionary spellcheck. What is to proper event to listen for?

Comment: Try the `input` event - that should also catch mouse drag-n-drop and any other methods of *input*.